# notifyDataSetChanged() Won't work properly

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am new to the custom adapter in ListView. I have created a custom adapter `ReminderToneAdapter`

```
 public class ReminderToneAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list ;
    private Context context;
    public ReminderToneAdapter(ArrayList<String> list,Context context)
    {
        this.list=list;
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }
    public void updateList(ArrayList<String> list2)
    {

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(list2);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View convertView=view;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_tone_item,null);
            TextView ringtoneText=convertView.findViewById(R.id.ringtone_text);
            ringtoneText.setText((i+1)+"."+list.get(i));
            Button removebutton=convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeTone_button);
            removebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Remove Tone Clicked" +i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    list.remove(i);

                    Iterator<String> iterators=list.iterator();
                    while(iterators.hasNext())
                    {
                        String currentItem=iterators.next();
                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+currentItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    updateList(list);

                }
            });
            ringtoneText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked text "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

the file reminder_tone_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:text="This is normal text"
android:gravity="start"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="@color/light_salnmon"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:id="@+id/ringtone_text"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/removeTone_button"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_horizontal_rule_24"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the Remove button, which is in front of the listView item, it should delete that item. But I didn't get the desired result. Whenever I click on any remove button it is clearing the whole listview.

Secondly, if I call `updateList()` as follows, to remove any item, it removes the last item:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<String> list2)
{

   // list.clear();  //commented
   //list.addAll(list2);//commented
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Can anyone explain this ambiguity?

Comment: I think no one is here in this community to solve this question.

Comment: solved it by adding else condition for if(convertview==null).Thanks and Regards